# Escape spaces in path in export variable (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, xdg-open

I use WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) and need to refer to edge-browser for xdg-open. Due to the space in the path I get an error. How can I escape the space? The path is shown corrrectly in exported variable BROWSER.

```
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ export BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 882: /mnt/c/Program: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 882: /mnt/c/Program: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221'
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ export BROWSER='/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe'
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 882: /mnt/c/Program: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 882: /mnt/c/Program: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221'
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ $BROWSER
-bash: /mnt/c/Program: No such file or directory
oliverk@KPW00WP3Q:/mnt/c/Users/E547766/Documents$ export
declare -x BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
```

Comment: Have you try with  \ (backslash)? `export BROWSER=/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe`

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Yeah, also does not work. And in this case there needs to be an additional \ in front of open and closing bracket.

Comment: Escape the brackets also :)

Comment: It works for me as I installed firefox in a location without spaces, but I would still be interested if there is a solution with spaces in bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $ export BROWSER="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
> $ xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683221
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: 882: /mnt/c/Program: not found
> ```

That error message hints a lot at word splitting in action.

And that's what it is. `xdg-open` is [a shell script](https://github.com/freedesktop/xdg-utils/blob/master/scripts/xdg-open.in#L375) that treats `$BROWSER` as a colon-separated list of browsers to try (similar to how `$PATH` works), and for each one, it tries to run

```
$browser "$url"
```

with the `$browser` unquoted. That means it gets split on whitespace(*), and there's nothing you can do about it. The downside of that is that paths with spaces won't work, and paths with glob characters might be a problem. The upside is that you can use it to pass arguments (provided that those arguments then don't need embedded whitespace etc.).

<sub>(* that's with the default `IFS`, which the script seems to use, unless it gets a modified value from outside the script and is run with a shell that neglects to reset `IFS` at the start of the script.)</sub>

The simplest workaround would probably be to create a symlink without whitespace in its path, point that to the browser and add the path to the symlink to `$BROWSER`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the old school Windows path with ~1

```
export BROWSER=/mnt/c/Progra~1/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```